Countable union of graphs of continuous functions is closed
As context, I am trying to prove that Borel sets are analytic, i.e. given a Polish space $X$, there is some Polish space $Y$ such that $B \subseteq X$ is Borel and is the image of a continuous function $f : Y \rightarrow X$. Now, following a proof am reading in Jech's Set Theory, we only need to prove that any Borel $B \subseteq X$ is the projection of a closed set $C \subseteq \mathcal{N} \times X$, i.e. $B = \pi_X(C)$ where $\pi_X$ is the projection function. Given that closed sets of Polish spaces (i.e. $\mathcal{N} \times X$) are Polish, and $\pi_X$ is continuous, the result follows by setting $Y$ as $\mathcal{N}$ and letting $C$ be $\{(x,f(x) : x \in \mathcal{N} \}$.
Of course, if $B$ is closed, we have that $B$ is the projection of some closed set $C \subseteq \mathcal{N} \times X$. But to prove the case whereby $B$ is open, we can use the fact that any open set in a Polish space is $F_{\sigma}$, i.e. the countable union of closed sets, i.e., we have $B = \bigcup_{i} F_i$, where the $F_i$'s are closed.
Now, in a proof am reading, we let $C_i \subseteq \mathcal{N} \times X$ be a sequence of closed sets such that $F_i = \pi_X(C_i)$ is closed in $X$. The proof concludes that since $\bigcup_i C_i$ is a closed set, we have the open set $B = \bigcup_{i} F_i = \pi_X(\bigcup_i C_i)$ as the projection of a closed set $\bigcup_i C_i$.
I am not so sure why $\bigcup_i C_i$ is closed. Here's my long-winded attempt:

Each $C_i \subseteq \mathcal{N} \times X$ is closed, being the graph of a continuous function, i.e. $C_i = \{(x,f(x)) : x \in \mathcal{N} \}$, following the sequential definition of continuity over metrizable spaces.

Assume each $C_i$ is nowhere-dense (haven't proven this yet but it makes sense since the graph of a continuous function in $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ is nowhere dense, but am not sure if this holds for $\mathcal{N} \times X$ given arbitrary Polish space $X$)...

$\bigcup_i C_i$ is a countable union of nowhere-dense sets

Given that any Polish Space has the Baire property (i.e. $\mathcal{N} \times X$ in this case), it follows that countable unions of nowhere-dense sets is nowhere-dense, i.e. $\bigcup_i C_i \subseteq \mathcal{N} \times X$ is closed.


Am I missing something ? Any help is really appreciated particularly in (2) above, i.e. is there a result that graphs of continuous functions in the Polish space $\mathcal{N} \times X$ is nowhere-dense ?

I'm not trying to follow everything, but I suspect you want to use the fact that every $F_{\sigma}$ set is a countable union of compact sets (replace each closed set with the (at most) countably many closed sets obtained by intersecting the closed set with closed balls of positive integer radii centered at the origin) and the fact that a continuous image of a compact set is compact (and hence closed). Incidentally, a countable union of graphs of continuous functions can be dense (even true for singleton sets), although FYI the graph of a continuous function is nowhere dense.

@DaveL.Renfro thanks for this I will take a look at the compactness angle... but if the product space is Baire, countable unions of nowhere dense graphs of continuous functions in that space should be nowhere dense right ?

product space is Baire --- I don't know -- I have not dealt with these kinds of details in quite a while (maybe not since mid 1990s).

@DaveL.Renfro okay thanks for your help

It seems to me that the graph of a continuous function can fail to be nowhere dense, for example if it's the graph of a constant function whose value is an isolated point. Can you reproduce or at least name the full proof you're talking about? I'm looking at the third edition of Jech. Is it Lemma 11.6? (I can't see where that proof claims that $\bigcup_i C_i$ is closed. )

@IzaakvanDongen, yes its in Lemma 11.6 where somewherr at the end of the proof, $\bigcup_n A_n$ is the projection of the closed set ${(x,c) : (x,c_{(0)}) \in F_{c_{(1)}(0)} }$. I let this set be $\bigcup_iC_i$ since $C_i$ is the notation I read in another text

@IzaakvanDongen, the other text am referring to is http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~marker/math512/dst.pdf, Lemma 4.5 page 35

Thank you! This set in Jech isn't a union though, is it? What's $C_i$ here? I think the point is to do some clever trickery using $\mathcal N \cong \mathcal N^\omega$ to avoid just taking a union of closed sets.

@IzaakvanDongen, oh okay ... I am thinking that $C_i = {(x,c_{0}) \in F_{c_{(1)}(0)} }$ where $i = c_{(1)}(0)$ ... but I guess am missing something

I'm not sure what your definition of $C_i$ means. But I think basically you should stop thinking about unions of closed sets. The point of the proof in Jech is that we can use the quantifier over $a \in \mathcal N$ to also quantify over $n \in \Bbb N$ "for free". Can you try to show that the set from Jech is closed directly - for example, that it's closed under limits of sequences? (Hint: remember what convergence in a product space means..)

@IzaakvanDongen thanks for that. Could you help me a bit with proving that Jech's definition is closed directly ? From what I understand, $c_{(0)} \in \mathcal{N}$ is the first coordinate of $\mathcal{N}^w$ (using the function $\mathcal{N} \rightarrow \mathcal{N}^{\omega}$), while $c_{(1)}(0) \in \mathbb{N}$ is some number ... but I don't see how this quantifies over $\mathbb{N}$ and that it is closed

Suppose $(x^{(n)}, c^{(n)}) \to (x, c)$ is a sequence in this set. Then $c_{(0)}^{(n)} \to c_{(0)}$ and $c_{(1)}^{(n)} \to c_{(1)}$. It follows that for sufficiently large $n$, we have $c_{(1)}^{(n)}(0) = c_{(1)}(0)$... Can you see why this means $(x, c)$ must lie in the set?

@IzaakvanDongen thanks! if I get it right, we have a continuous $\Gamma : \mathcal{N} \rightarrow \mathcal{N} \times \mathcal{N}^{\omega}$ along with a continuous $f : \mathcal{N} \rightarrow X$ ($f$ is used to show a subset of $X$ is analytic) ... By continuity of $\Gamma$ over Polish $\mathcal{N}$, if $c^{(n)} \rightarrow c$ then $c^{(n)}{(0)} \rightarrow c{(0)}$ and the same for $c_{(1)}$ ...  Given $c^{(n)}{(0)} \rightarrow c{(0)}$, by continuity of $f$, we get $f(c_{(0)}^{(n)}) \rightarrow f(c_{(0)}) = x$, i.e. $(x,c_{(0)}) \in F_{c_{(1)}(0)}$, so the graph ${(x,c_{(0)})}$ is closed

@IzaakvanDongen, here, I assumed the existence of $f$, from the given analytic set $A_n ={x : \exists a (x,a) \in F_n }$ in Jech's proof, so that basically $f(a) \in A_n$ for all $a \in \mathcal{N}$

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
